# Provide inject with setup function with Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Anybody knows how to provide a variable that is in the setup function?

```
export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  provide: {
    myVariableThatIWantToProvide // This is not working
  },
  setup() {
    const myVariableThatIWantToProvide = ref('test');

    return {
      myVariableThatIWantToProvide
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should import `provide` from vue and use inside the setup function :

```
import {ref,provide} from "vue"
export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
 
  setup() {
    const myVariableThatIWantToProvide = ref('test');
      provide ('myVariableThatIWantToProvide', myVariableThatIWantToProvide )
    return {
      myVariableThatIWantToProvide
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

in grandchild component :

```
import {inject} from "vue"
export default {
  name: "somechild",
 
  setup() {
      const myVariableThatIWantToProvide =inject ('myVariableThatIWantToProvide')
    return {
      myVariableThatIWantToProvide
    };
  }
};
</script>
```