# How do I make a variable available to a grandchild component in this Vue 3 application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am working on a *Vue 3* app. I have run into a problem working with a *parent component*, a child component and a *grandchild component*.

In `Main.vue` (parent compenent):

```
<template>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <Filters
         :usersData='users' 
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Filters from './Ui/Filters'
    export default {
      name: 'Posts',
      components: {
        Filters
      },
      props: {
        title: String,
      },
    }
</script>
```

In the *child compenent* `Filters.vue`:

```
<template>
    <label>Filter by author</label>
    <MyDropdown
        label="All authors" 
        :usersData='users'
        />
</template>

<script>
    import MyDropdown from './MyDropdown'
    import MyButton from './MyButton'

    export default {

      name: 'Filters',

      components: {
        MyDropdown,
        MyButton
      },

      props: {
        usersData: Object
     },

    data() {
        return {
          url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
          users: [],
        }
    },
    async mounted() {
        // Users
        await this.axios.get(`${this.url}/users`).then((response) => {
          if (response.status == 200) {
            this.users = response.data;
            console.log(this.users); // outputs the users correctly
          }
        }).catch((errors) => {
          console.log(errors);
        });
      }
    }
</script>
```

Tn the grandchild component `MyDropdown.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
       {{ label }}
    </button>
    <ul v-if="usersData.length" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Jane Doe</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">John Doe</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      name: 'MyDropdown',
      props: {
        label: String,
        usersData: Object
      }
    }
</script>
```

#### The problem

As long as `v-if="usersData.length` is present, I get this error in the console:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

##### Where is my mistake?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65259675/8172857

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if it is just avoiding your error in the `MyDropDown` grandchild component you can just add a `?` after the usersData variable like `v-if="usersData?.length"`. This will remove your `Can't read length of undefined` error.
Next is the way you're trying to pass your props from parent to the child component. You are passing your `users` data to `usersData` prop of the `Filters` component tag but are trying to get the props as `filterData` in the component, which will not work as expected. So `users` is considered with an `undefined` value and is being the same into your grandchild which is causing an error in your grandchild i.e. `MyDropDown` component.
Try mapping the prop names properly and avoid variable name repetition with that of the prop names inside any component.
If you are trying to send data from parent to grandchild directly you use the `Provide/Inject` feature of Vue.js.
Find more about it here [Provide/Inject | Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html)

Comment: Thanks for the pertinent observations, I have corrected the `filterData` issue. I do not insist on passing the variable from parent to grandchild _directly_, I just want it in the grandchild in the easiest, most comprehensive way.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir gave an answer for the same. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
v-if="usersData?.length > 0"
```

try this
or

```
v-if="usersData.length > 0"
```