# How to pass props to the nested component directly in Vue Js 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Imagine a scenario, `App.vue >> Todo.vue >> Popup.vue >> Field.vue`. How can I pass props from `Todo.vue` directly to `Field.vue` component? Or let's say in a more complex nested component structure.

I know we can use stores but I would like to know if Vue js 3 have api something like "Context" in Svelte JS?

Looking forward.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65259675/8172857

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisely the scenario you describe is [explained in the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html)

In short:

*Todo.vue*

```
provide('keyForYourProvidedProp', valueForYourProvidedProp);
```

*Field.vue*

```
const message = inject('keyForYourProvidedProp');
```

Be sure to check your the article in the docs I've provided